# Como enviar de forma correcta un array por Postman

Tags: php, symfony, postman

Trabajo con `Symfony`, `PHP` en una `API`, tengo la necesidad de enviar un array por `Postman`, el cual en el `backend` espera un `JSON` no se cual es el formato correcto. Tengo el siguiente array

```
"quimestre1":{"fecha_inicio_q":"2016-05-02",
"fecha_fin_q":"2016-10-07",
"fecha_inicio_parcial1":"2016-05-02",
"fecha_fin_parcial1":"2016-06-26",
"fecha_inicio_parcial2":"2016-06-27",
"fecha_fin_parcial2":"2016-08-15",
"fecha_inicio_parcial3":"2016-08-15",
"fecha_fin_parcial3":"2016-10-06"}
```

De esta manera la tengo registrada en la base de datos en un campo de tipo `string`

Lo debo de enviar de la siguiente manera?

```
{
"periodo":"2025-2026",
"periodoestado":"ACTIVO",
"configAnioLectivo":[
    {
        "fecha_inicio_anio":"2017-04-24",
        "fecha_fin_anio":"2018-02-09",
        "quimestre1":{
            "fecha_inicio_q":"2017-04-24","fecha_fin_q":"2017-09-22","fecha_inicio_parcial1":"2017-04-24","fecha_fin_parcial1":"2017-06-14","fecha_inicio_parcial2":"2017-06-14","fecha_fin_parcial2":"2017-08-03","fecha_inicio_parcial3":"2017-08-04","fecha_fin_parcial3":"2017-09-18"
            },
        "quimestre2":{
            "fecha_inicio_q":"2017-09-25","fecha_fin_q":"2018-02-09","fecha_inicio_parcial1":"2017-09-25","fecha_fin_parcial1":"2017-11-12","fecha_inicio_parcial2":"2017-11-13","fecha_fin_parcial2":"2017-12-31","fecha_inicio_parcial3":"2018-01-02","fecha_fin_parcial3":"2018-02-09"
            }
    } 
] 
}
```

De esta manera me da el siguiente error:`"errors": [ "Este formulario no debería contener campos adicionales."`

El backend que es `Symfony` `PHP` espera lo siguiente.

```
"vars": {
    "value": {
        "periodo": "2025-2026",
        "config_anio_lectivo": {
            "quimestre1": [],
            "quimestre2": []
        }
    },
```

He probado de esta otra manera

```
 "configAnioLectivo":[
   {"fecha_inicio_anio":"2018-04-04","fecha_fin_anio":"2019-02-01",
    "quimestre1":[{"fecha_inicio_q":"2018-04-04","fecha_fin_q":"2018-09-15","fecha_inicio_parcial1":"2018-04-04","fecha_fin_parcial1":"2018-06-11","fecha_inicio_parcial2":"2018-06-11","fecha_fin_parcial2":"2018-07-25","fecha_inicio_parcial3":"2018-07-26","fecha_fin_parcial3":"2018-09-06"}],
    "quimestre2":[{"fecha_inicio_q":"2018-09-17","fecha_fin_q":"2018-02-01","fecha_inicio_parcial1":"2018-09-17","fecha_fin_parcial1":"2018-10-29","fecha_inicio_parcial2":"2018-10-30","fecha_fin_parcial2":"2018-12-29","fecha_inicio_parcial3":"2019-01-02","fecha_fin_parcial3":"2019-02-05"}]}
]
```

Me sale el mismo error:`"Este formulario no debería contener campos adicionales."`

Lo que tengo registrado en la db es lo siguiente lo que hizo otra persona

```
 {"fecha_inicio_anio":"2018-04-04","fecha_fin_anio":"2019-02-01",
"quimestre1":{"fecha_inicio_q":"2018-04-04","fecha_fin_q":"2018-09-15","fecha_inicio_parcial1":"2018-04-04","fecha_fin_parcial1":"2018-06-11","fecha_inicio_parcial2":"2018-06-11","fecha_fin_parcial2":"2018-07-25","fecha_inicio_parcial3":"2018-07-26","fecha_fin_parcial3":"2018-09-06"},
"quimestre2":{"fecha_inicio_q":"2018-09-17","fecha_fin_q":"2018-02-01","fecha_inicio_parcial1":"2018-09-17","fecha_fin_parcial1":"2018-10-29","fecha_inicio_parcial2":"2018-10-30","fecha_fin_parcial2":"2018-12-29","fecha_inicio_parcial3":"2019-01-02","fecha_fin_parcial3":"2019-02-05"}}
```

Comment: Te has respondido tu mismo, si el backend espera lo que enseñas, eso mismo debes armar desde el postman. tal cual lo que armaste en tu ultima linea de código de la pregunta.

Comment: @jorgeGomez No se como armar el array puede ser de esta manera `"configAnioLectivo":[
        "quimestre1":[
                {"fecha_inicio_q":"2018-04-04"},
                {"fecha_fin_q":"2018-09-15"},
                {"fecha_inicio_parcial1":"2018-04-04"},
                {"fecha_fin_parcial1":"2018-06-11"},
                {"fecha_inicio_parcial2":"2018-06-11"},
                {"fecha_fin_parcial2":"2018-07-25"},
                {"fecha_inicio_parcial3":"2018-07-26"},
                {"fecha_fin_parcial3":"2018-09-06"}
            ],`

Comment: Si lo que espera recibir empieza por `vars`, luego va `value` que tiene `periodo` y `config_anio_lectivo`.... como le pasas un objeto que empieza directamente con `configAnioLectivo`? Para empezar, en un lado declaras la clave con lower_snake_case, y en el otro camelCase, con lo cual no son la misma key. Luego, postman no añade wrappers por ti, así que tendrás que empezar el objeto con `"vars":{"value":{"periodo": "2025-2026, "config_anio_lectivo": {"quimestre1": [....]}}}`

Comment: Repecto a tu observación yo no he implemetado el código por eso que utilizan varias nomenclaturas no un standard

Comment: Que opinan de otra solución de hacerlo de cero? convertir un array a json con el formato que necesito.

Comment: Si estamos hablando de JSON, un array tiene el formato `[a, b, c, d..]` y no `{a:v1,b:v2...}.`... eso es un objeto "diccionario"

Comment: @PabloLozano este array se convierte a json lo que espera el backend es un json, en tu respuesta también aplica de dentro del` [a,b,c,d.. puden ir otros array como Quimestre1 y Quimestre2]`?

Comment: Actualice la pregunta dando mas información para que me puedan ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mira mediante esta prueba sencilla en `Javascript` puedes darte cuenta como debe lucir el `string` de tu cadena de caracteres en formato `json`:

simplemente debes presentar el Objeto con sus propiedades y hacer la conversión con `stringify`

```js
let object_test = {
  "quimestre1":{
    "fecha_inicio_q":"2016-05-02",
    "fecha_fin_q":"2016-10-07",
    "fecha_inicio_parcial1":"2016-05-02",
    "fecha_fin_parcial1":"2016-06-26",
    "fecha_inicio_parcial2":"2016-06-27",
    "fecha_fin_parcial2":"2016-08-15",
    "fecha_inicio_parcial3":"2016-08-15",
    "fecha_fin_parcial3":"2016-10-06"
    }
};

let text_json_test = JSON.stringify(object_test)

console.log('Verificando el Tipo');
console.log('object ==',typeof object_test);
console.log('string ==',typeof text_json_test);

console.log('output con formato');
console.log(object_test);
console.log(text_json_test);
```

el output en texto es:

```
{"quimestre1":{"fecha_inicio_q":"2016-05-02","fecha_fin_q":"2016-10-07","fecha_inicio_parcial1":"2016-05-02","fecha_fin_parcial1":"2016-06-26","fecha_inicio_parcial2":"2016-06-27","fecha_fin_parcial2":"2016-08-15","fecha_inicio_parcial3":"2016-08-15","fecha_fin_parcial3":"2016-10-06"}}
```

nota: sin espacios ni saltos de linea.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta para enviarlo por POSTMAN aca te muestro un ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Mauricio estaba a punto de instalarlo para hacer lo mismo XD

Comment: Con gusto desde hoy estare mas atento a esta comunidad, parece estar muy olvidada

Comment: otra cosa @MauricioGraciaGutierrez el OP aparte de no saber como emplear POSTMAN tampoco sabia armas el JSON correctamente; eso lo discutimos en el chat de sitio: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: si claro, pero en la respuesta original que yo edita decia "y asi se hace un POST" cuando la pregunta era "como lo hago en postman" por eso le quite ese parrafo

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez El problema no es que el sitio esté olvidado, la pregunta como la platenó la persona no era entendible, como lo había exrpresado. La fué ajustando según fué entendiendo lo que le preguntaban.

Comment: Caundo tu vas a https://es.stackoverflow.com veras que hay preguntas que llevan horas o dias sin ni una sola respuesta eso no es buen indicio, no quiero decir que no haya personas participando ni esfrozandose