# Realizar petición post con curl

Tags: php, python, curl

Estaba tratando de realizar una petición `post` en php mediante el uso de `file_get_contents` pero al momento de pasarle los *headers* al parecer no me los tomaba ya que siempre especificaba otro `Content-type` al que le había puesto por defecto. Dado a ese problema decidí usar `curl` para realizar la petición, tal que así:

```php
function send_post(string $url, array $headers, array $body){
    
    $headers["Host"] = $this->host;
    $headers = $this->arrHeader_from_array($headers);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    return "--->".$result;

}
```

La función `arrHeader_from_array` lo que hace es convertir un array asociativo con esta estructura (resultado de un `var_dump`):

```php
array(7) {
["Accept"]=>
string(3) "*/*"
["Content-Type"]=>
string(16) "application/json"
["Content-Length"]=>
string(2) "67"
["Accept-Encoding"]=>
string(17) "gzip, deflate, br"
["Host"]=>
string(14) "127.0.0.1:8080"
["Connection"]=>
string(5) "close"
}
```

A algo como esto:

```php
array(7) {
[0]=>
string(11) "Accept: */*"
[1]=>
string(30) "Content-Type: application/json"
[2]=>
string(18) "Content-Length: 67"
[3]=>
string(34) "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
[4]=>
string(22) "Host: http://127.0.0.1"
[5]=>
string(17) "Connection: close"
}
```

Y como `body` se le pasa lo siguiente:

```php
array(2) {
["username"]=>
string(17) "email@mail.com"
["password"]=>
string(8) "password"
}
```

Al final el resultado que obtengo es esto:

```
---><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)</p>
```

Por pura curiosidad se me ocurrió cambiar el contenido del `body` de la petición `curl`

```php
...
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'postvars=val1&postvars2=val2');
...
```

Y resulta que mi servidor no devuelve ninguna respuesta, quedo esperando por un largo tiempo y tengo que reiniciar el servidor.

El código completo es el siguiente:

```php
<?php
class Redir {
    function __construct(string $url, int $port){
        $this->host = $url;
        $this->port = $port;
    }

    function arrHeader_from_array(array $headers){
        $arr_header=[];
        foreach($headers as $header=>$value){
            array_push($arr_header,"$header: $value");
        }
        return $arr_header;
    }

    function send_post(string $url, array $headers, array $body){
        
        $headers["Host"] = $this->host;
        $headers = $this->arrHeader_from_array($headers);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        return "--->".$result;

    }
    static function getallheaders(){
        foreach($_SERVER as $K=>$V){
            $a=explode('_' ,$K);
            if(array_shift($a)=='HTTP'){
                array_walk($a,function(&$v){
                    $v=ucfirst(strtolower($v));
                });
                $retval[join('-',$a)]=$V;
            }
        }
        return $retval;
    }

    function start(){
        $req = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
         if ($req == "POST"){
            $route = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
            //print_r($body);
            $url = "$this->host:$this->port".$route;
            $headers = $this->getallheaders();
            //print_r($headers);

            echo $this->send_post($url, $headers, $body);
            return;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Y el servidor que recibirá la petición es un servidor python hecho con `flask`:

```py
@app.post("/data")
def data():
    print(request.json, request.headers)
    return "yep"
```

Al enviar la información usando `json_encode($body)` el problema es el mismo, la petición no envía respuesta y parece ser eterna.
Entonces ¿Cómo es que debo hacer la petición curl?

Comment: ¿Probaste a enviar `$body` como JSON en lugar de un arreglo? `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($body));`

Comment: sip, y ocurre lo mismo que si lo enviara como string, la petición no da un resultado

Comment: ¿La API es tuya o de terceros? Si no es tuya, ¿hay documentación?

Comment: Es mia, mi servidor php en `localhost:8080` recibe una petición `post` y realiza la misma petición a `localhost:4000` el cual es un servidor en python, que lo único que tiene es un `print(request.headers); return "yep"`

Comment: Parece que la API espera un JSON, y a lo que parece PHP debe de estar enviando un formulario form-encoded, debido a que le has pasado un diccionario para el body. Quizás sea mucho más simple que envíes en el cuerpo una mera cadena `"{\"username\": \"email@mail.com\", \"password\": \"password\" }"`

Comment: @abulafia haría esto `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"username\": \"email@mail.com\", \"password\": \"password\" }");` ?

Comment: [Sí](https://omnipc.ddns.net/yodiriaque.html?answer=si,%20eso)

Comment: @abulafia vaya sitio más útil. Lo acabo de probar e intentando imprimir `request.json`  y pues lo mismo.... la petición no parece acabar

Comment: Entonces, en la API toma el valor así: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` para obtener los datos del flujo de entrada.

Comment: @Triby exactamente

Comment: Enviando los datos con json_encode() (o la cadena sugerida por @abulafia) y tomándolos del flujo de entrada debería funcionar.

Comment: @Triby lo he intentado pero como digo la petición parece no terminar al tratar de imprimir los resultados

Comment: @abulafia no será alguna cosa que haga flask?

Comment: Intenta no manipular la información y mostrar en pantalla: `$data = file_get_contents('php://input'); var_dump($data, $_POST, $_GET); die();` y cuéntanos lo que obtienes.

Comment: @Triby retorna `array(2) {
["username"]=>
string(14) "email@mail.com"
["password"]=>
string(8) "password"
}
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}`

Comment: Entonces sí tienes acceso a los datos con `$data['username']` y `$data['password']`, por lo que el problema puede estar en otra parte. Agrega el código de la API para tratar de ver dónde está el error.

Comment: Pero ¿a ti te interesa recuperar los header en la respuesta? No conozco python pero intuyo que aquí estarías mandando dos salidas: `print(request.json, request.headers)` Si te interesan también los headers tendrías que crear un solo objeto y mandarlo en respuesta desde el servidor, de lo contrario, se estaría mandando un json inválido.

Comment: @Triby todo el código que utilizo esta en la pregunta (salvo el instanciar la clase)

Comment: @A.Cedano lo headers que envía python no me interesa, además el `print` de python es distinto al `echo` de php, con `print()` solo se me muestra por consola y lo que en realidad retorna es lo que está en el `return`

Comment: En Python creo que deberías obtener los datos con `request_data = request.get_json()` al menos según lo que vi en [este enlace](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask-es#uso-de-datos-json)

Comment: He realizado algunas pruebas y diria que el problema está más en el lado del servidor/servicio donde va a parar la petición que en tu código en PHP.  He abierto un puerto con `netcat -l <puerto>` y he forzado tu script para que vaya alli, y recibo los datos de forma correcta, pero como no devuelvo nada se quedan pensando eternamente en el navegador... y quizas ahi tienes el problema, que no debes devolver nada desde python por lo que sea

Comment: @Triby tanto `request.get_json()` como `request.json` regresan el mismo contenido en forma de diccionario

Comment: @masterguru si no devuelvo nada en python flask me marca error, ya que se espera que se devuelva un json siempre (o un diccionario)

Comment: Desconozco Python y me fui con lo primero que vi, lo siento. Acabo de agregar la etiqueta para ver si alguien con mayor experiencia puede aportar algo útil.

Comment: @Christian pues comprueba lo que envias en un terminal con el `netcat -l <puerto>` e instancia con `$redir = new Redir("127.0.0.1", "<puerto>");$redir->start();` y miralo tu mismo a ver si llega y **que** llega

Comment: @Triby esta bien, aunque la respuesta me funciona, aún me queda la duda de por qué mi código no funionaba

Comment: @masterguru levanté el servidor con `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: @Christian mmm... no se si acabo de entenderlo pues... no voy a hacerme más pesado, pero el `netcat` te muestra en el terminal donde se queda a la escucha todo lo que se manda realmente con las cabeceras, etc, en modo texto tal cual se mandan. Es un recurso más a tener en cuenta para depurar segun que cosas, por si no lo sabias.

Comment: @masterguru Haa.... shap, no lo sabía, ahora mismo lo pruebo

Comment: @masterguru devuelve `POST /data HTTP/1.1
user-agent: Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.com)
accept: */*
content-type: application/json
content-length: 64
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: close

{
    "username": "email@mail.com",
    "password": "password"
}`

Comment: @Christian Pues a mi me devuelve todo un churro de información, para terminar con un par de cosas asi:  `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username" email@email.com` pero no hago el json_decode, le meto directamente un array asociativo con los datos. Supongo que es por esto: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;` en lugar del `application/json`

Comment: @Christian en fin, tu mismo, ahora ya puedes ver lo que mandas y como lo mandas, a partir de aqui puedes depurar algo mejor espero

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133793/discussion-on-question-by-christian-realizar-peticion-post-con-curl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola en mi caso cuando implemento CURL utilizo la siguiente forma:

#### A. Script CURL para enviar datos:

***Explicación:***

1. Primero que nada me gusta anidar informacion, por eso veras que la variable `$fields` es un array que a su vez contiene otro array en formato `json`.
2. al enviar algo en formato json descarto el uso de `http_build_query`
3. en la cabecera sobre escribo el método con `POST` y indico el header: `"Content-Type: application/json"`
4. armo un Array en donde coloco todos los `CURLOPT_*` como veras en ultima instancia es que hago el `json_encode` de la variable `$fields` y que `CURLOPT_POST`  le estoy pasando un true en lugar del conteo de campos.

***Ejemplo:***

```php
/*Envios de Datos en formato JSON con Header Especificos*/
$fields   = [
    'body' => [
        'correo' => 'email@email', 
        'contraseña' => 'dfgsdfhdsfgdsfg'
    ]
];
//$postvars = http_build_query($fields);
$headers = [
    "X-HTTP-Method-Override: POST",
    "Content-Type: application/json" 
];
$url = "http://test3.me/test.php";
$ch = curl_init();
$defaults = [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($fields),
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true
];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $defaults);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

#### B. Recepción de Datos:

***Explicación:***

1. Empleo el método php `getallheaders()` para capturar la cabecera del Request.
2. Hago la lectura de los datos desde "php://input" utilizando `file_get_contents`

***Ejemplo:***

```php
<?php

echo 'Hello World!!!';

echo '<pre>';

echo var_dump(getallheaders());

$json = file_get_contents("php://input");

$data1 = json_decode($json);

echo '<br><br>';
echo var_dump($data1);
echo '<br><br>';


echo $data1->body->correo;  //Acceder en formato de propiedad de un Objeto
echo '<br><br>';

$data2 = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data2['body']['correo']; //Acceder en formato Array

echo '</pre>';
```

#### Output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otros POST que talvez te interesen:

[Convertir array clave valor en objeto php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499660/convertir-array-clave-valor-en-objeto-php)

[Obtener clave valor de una matriz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/487898/obtener-clave-valor-de-una-matriz)

[Como enviar de forma correcta un array por Postman](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/423290/como-enviar-de-forma-correcta-un-array-por-postman)

[Como extraer un valor de una URL JSON a PHP dándole un formato?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/496821/como-extraer-un-valor-de-una-url-json-a-php-d%c3%a1ndole-un-formato)

Comment: no sé que habré estado haciendo pero con tu código funciona, gracias :D

Comment: @Christian yo tampoco  se que estabas haciendo .... tienes tantos métodos que decidí hacerlo de la forma simple... en lugar de buscar tu error ...

Comment: jajaja, tiene sentido, lo mismo hago con las preguntas de python

Comment: te recomiendo programas de lo mas básico a lo mas avanzado ... aveces un simple cambio en la estructura provoca que deje de funcionar...

Comment: **heisenbug** ahora ya me funciona :/